# WebView in RelativeLayout doesn't center

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I have a layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When looking the the Android Studio layout designer, the WebView is centred as expected. When pushed onto a device or run in the emulator, the WebView is left justified, ignoring the `centerHorizontal` tag. Below is a screenshot with show view bounds enabled.

[image: Example output with show view bounds enabled]

How can I get the WebView to centre?

Comment: did you try using `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Comment: Yes. Same left justified result.

Comment: I think the problem might be with your `android:layout_width="400dp"` which should not be fixed, try to make it `match_parent` or `wrap_content` as per your requirement

Comment: But I want the width of the WebView to be 400dp.

This is in a layout-w600dp layout for use when the tablet is in landscape, hoping to present the user with a nice width column of content to read so there's less scanning left to right.

Comment: please show parent xml code for RelativeLayout

Comment: did u try 
**android:gravity="center"**

Comment: AH! Thanks @AhmadAlkhateeb! The parent FrameLayout has height and width set to wrap_content. Please put together an answer below and I'll accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the parent was set as **match_parent** like this .

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
       </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

Comment: Thanks again. I was hoping it was something simple and I just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make a view centre aligned, You can use android:centre on the parent view.It will work.
So,the code will change as

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="centre">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i hope this will help you :)